# MongoEngine python library filter query get native mongo syntax

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

There is different way to filter the mongo query provided by mongoengine python library to connect to MongoDB. We can use different [Query operators](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html?highlight=inc__#filtering-queries).

But this is MongoEngine implementation, MongoDB can't understand that, mongoengine has to convert that to syntax understand by MongoDB native syntax.

For example:

```
model.objects(field__in=[1])
```

is actual query in MongoDB as

```
db.collection.find({field: {$in: [1]}})
```

or

```
models.objects(field__lt=5)
```

is actual query in MongoDB as

```
db.collection.find({field: {$lt: 5}})
```

I am looking for some method where I can pass `field__in=[1]` and it would return me `{field: {$in: [1]}}`.

I need this to generate aggregate [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#match-aggregation). MongoEngine [`model.objects.aggregate`](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate) will return `pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor` object and it not support filtering as supported by [QuerySet](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet) means, I cant do like `model.objects.aggregate(XXXX)(field__in=[1])`.

I can do `model.objects(field__in=[1]).aggregate(XXX)` but this is wrong, we are doing filter before the aggregate, but I want to do filter on aggregate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method in mongoengine that will provide this.

```
from mongoengine.queryset.transform import query
```

Without giving a source `Document` the results will be pretty generic.

```
>> query(title="hello")
{'title': 'hello'}

>> query(title__contains="hello")
{'title': 'hello'}
```

If you define a `Document` and provide it to the query, each field type will know to to processes the query correctly:

```
>> from mongoengine import Document, fields

>> class Test(Document):
>>    title = fields.StringField()

>> query(Test, title="hello")
{'title': 'hello'}

>> query(Test, title__contains="hello")
{'title': re.compile(r'hello', re.UNICODE)}
```